# jQuery Mobile List Within a LIst

Tags: jquery, list, mobile

I want to create a list within a list item on jQuery mobile here's my code:

https://gist.github.com/2886812

Eveything works out properly except the top and bottom list items get cut off and look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIJX4.jpg

I don't even know if what I want to do is possible. I'm a novice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/7wzbR/

Comment: Thank you that works pretty well, only thing is there's not dark lines separating the items like in a list, any idea how to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: When I add a border to the buttons all the go to the left side.